# Call a method in another class from a control within a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I have a custom control created, comprised of a bunch of text boxes, 1 button and radio buttons.

I then have a "parent" control which only has this 1 custom control placed on it, and in the code behind I have a reference to **this** control's Presenter.

The presenter handles the actual code for searching (when the one button is pressed). How do I set up the button click event on the child control to call the Search method from the presenter?

So I have the following:

```
CtlSearchDetails
ViewSearchScreen
PresenterSearchScreen
```

The button click event is on `CtlSearchDetails` and it needs to call the method on `PresenterSearchScreen`. I cannot figure out how to reveal this method to the instace of the control on `ViewSearchScreen`.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom child control, you want to expose an event for the button click:

```
public event Action OnButtonClicked;
```

Then hook the button clicked event from the designer

```
private void btn_myButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (OnButtonClicked != null)
    OnButtonClicked();
}
```

Then in your parent container, you want to handle this event from the child control

```
this.myChildControl.OnButtonClicked += new Action(onChildButtonClicked);

private void onChildButtonClicked()
{
  // Do your search here
}
```